# Custom 404.13 error in IIS7.5 without uploading entire file

Tags: file-upload, error-handling, iis-7.5

Using IIS7.5 running MVC3, I have limited file upload size in web.config to 5MB

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5120" executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="5242880"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

This works and a 404 error page is displayed when anyone attempts to upload a file larger than 5MB.

I then set a custom error page in IIS for the site under Error Pages and added the default C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US\404-13.htm page to be used for this error. This page is now displayed when the file size exceeds 5MB but before the page is displayed the entire file is uploaded.

Is there a way around this? If I remove the custom 404.13 error the old 404 page is instant and it looks like nothing even gets uploaded. That's what I want just with a custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found the solution to this, but you can use IIS level filtering on your server, and it appears to return instantaneously if a file is too large for upload.

Have a look at this

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits